# Button to delete a grid of squares only works once - Node.removeChild: The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, css, dom, dom-events

I am doing an etch-a-sketch project and so far it has gone well. I wanted to challenge myself by making a button to "destroy" the new grid that I create with another button.

The problem is the button only works once, then throws the error: **Node.removeChild: The node to be removed is not** a child of this node**

**I solved this** after trial and error, by moving my `const` variable out of the global scope and inside the `destroyBtn` function. **The problem is I don't know why it works.** If it's in the global scope, shouldn't `querySelectorAll('.grid')` always be accessible / targetting a newly created grid?? Thanks for your time.

This works:

```js
const containerBtn = document.querySelector('.container')
const destroyBtn = document.querySelector('#destroybtn')

destroyBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const targetSquares = document.querySelectorAll('.grid') // moved inside function
    for (let i = 0; i < targetSquares.length; i++) {
        containerBtn.removeChild(targetSquares[i])
        
    }
})
```

This does not:

```js
const containerBtn = document.querySelector('.container')
const destroyBtn = document.querySelector('#destroybtn')
const targetSquares = document.querySelectorAll('.grid') // in global scope

destroyBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < targetSquares.length; i++) {
        containerBtn.removeChild(targetSquares[i])
        
    }
})
```

Comment: When its in global scope, `targetSquares` stores `.grid` node once. After you remove all child (from EventListener), `targetSquares` variable got empty. That why you have to select element everytime after click.

Comment: Thank you! Is this only specific to `const` variables that create or query elements?

Comment: Its not about const, Its about assigning value to variable and using it properly